# Angular2 Newbie Passing data from Parent to Child component

Tags: angular

I am looking at a sample Angular 2 project and inserted some code to try to pull the value from a movie object that is passed to a nested child component.

In the parent code, I have the following:

```
<div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-3 col-xs-6" *ngFor="let movie of movies; let i = index;">
  <movie-card [movie]="movie"></movie-card>
</div>
```

In my movie-card.component.ts file  I have this code:

```
import { Component, Input } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'movie-card',
  templateUrl: './movie-card.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./movie-card.component.css']
})
export class MovieCardComponent {

  @Input()
  movie: Object;

  constructor() {

  console.log('movie : ' + this.movie);
  }

}
```

The output to my Chrome console is:

```
20 movie : undefined  movie-card.component.ts:15
```

But in the movie-card.component.html

```
 {{movie.Name}}
```

the html will output the movie name.

I want to send the movie.Name value to my service like this.

```
_anatomyService.getImage(this.movie.Name);
```

However the value of movie is undefined. What am I not understanding?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the set on your value

```
import { Component, Input } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'movie-card',
  templateUrl: './movie-card.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./movie-card.component.css']
})
export class MovieCardComponent {

  @Input()
  set movie(movie: Object){
   console.log(movie);
    //asign it to a value or do something with it
  }

}
```

Answer (score 2):

your movie-card.component.ts should be like this.

```
    import { Component, Input, OnInit  } from '@angular/core'; <-- add OnInit 

    @Component({
      selector: 'movie-card',
      templateUrl: './movie-card.component.html',
      styleUrls: ['./movie-card.component.css']
    })
    export class MovieCardComponent {

      @Input()
      movie: Object;

      constructor() { }

    ngOnInit() {     <-- your this.movie should be in ngOnInit lifecycle hook
         console.log('movie : ' + this.movie);
       }

    }
```

check this link for more life cycle hooks http://learnangular2.com/lifecycle/

Answer (score 1):

There is no initialized input value inside constructor. You have to wait until `ngOnInit()`

```
ngOnInit() {
  console.log('movie : ' + this.movie);
}
```

See also more details about angular2 lifecycle here

- https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/lifecycle-hooks.html